# Select2 search input does not receive focus upon opening

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, jquery-select2

I'm having an issue with select2 dropdowns retaining focus upon being opened.

Basically when you click on a dropdown with select2 a special select2 dropdown is shown with a text input at the top so you can start typing and narrow down your select options. Well, when the select2 dropdown opens the focus is NOT in the search input. Its still on the original select html element.

This is a WORKING select2 dropdown on CodePen just as an example. I can't replicate the issue I'm having within CodePen, so it makes me think its something conflicting on my site. But I don't know what and I can't seem to narrow it down.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/QmoGew

```
see codepen for sample working code
```

I can see the focus go into the search input upon opening but it immediately goes away. Does anyone have any ideas why this could be happening??

Here are my dependencies from my package.json file:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.17",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "browser-sync": "^2.23.6",
    "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^2.2.2",
    "cross-env": "^5.1.4",
    "jquery": "^3.2",
    "laravel-mix": "^2.1.11",
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",
    "vue": "^2.5.16",
    "vue-resource": "^0.9.3",
    "vue-router": "^2.6.0",
    "vuex": "^2.5.0",
    "webpack": "^3.10.0"
},
"dependencies": {
    "dropzone": "^5.4.0",
    "mini-toastr": "^0.7.2",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.3",
    "sweetalert": "^2.1.0",
    "vue-notifications": "^0.9.0",
    "select2": "^4.0.6-rc.1"
}
```

And this is how I am compiling everything within webpack.mix.js

```
mix.browserSync('127.0.0.1:8000')
    .js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .styles([
        'node_modules/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css',
        'node_modules/dropzone/dist/min/dropzone.min.css',
        'node_modules/select2/dist/css/select2.min.css'
    ], 'public/css/libs.css')
    .sourceMaps()
    .version();

mix.combine([
    'node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
    'node_modules/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js',
    'node_modules/dropzone/dist/min/dropzone.min.js',
    'node_modules/select2/dist/js/select2.full.min.js'
], 'public/js/app.js')
.sourceMaps();
```

Comment: maybe you want to post here how you implemented your code including other scripts. Maybe there's conflict with other javascripts you have.

Comment: Ok, I updated the post to include my package.json and my webpack config.

Comment: As I see in your codepen and in your webpack, they are not the same version, did you test the version that is in the codepen? Maybe not using the full, instead select2.min.js only

Answer (score -3):

```
$('#element_id').select2('open');
```

Should do the trick !

Comment: That did not do the trick. :( I tried what you suggested but I"m still having the same issue. Thank you for help. Any other ideas?

Comment: I think you have some sort of browser problem because I opened up your codepen example and I opened the select input and every time search input was in focus and it was not going away at all.

Comment: This idea did not work.